# Issue with rendering Angularjs 2 PrimeNG Schedule component

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to integrate the PrimeNg Schedule component to angularjs  2 application.I downloaded the seed project from the below url

https://yakovfain.com/2016/10/06/primeng-ui-components-for-angular-2/

Imported the module

```
import {ScheduleModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

And added the below line in the template for the schedule to appear,

```
<p-schedule></p-schedule>
```

Then I got an error

'p-schedule' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-schedule' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-schedule' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

So I went in and added the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA under schemas in NgModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Now I cannot see any errors in my console, but I am getting a blank page. Any idea what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the current project and started a new one from the below git repo

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-cli

and included the fullcalendar, moment and jquery modules and now it is rendering as expected.

Thanks everybody for the help.